# HTML to display a PDF in a portion of rendered page?

Tags: pdf, website, html, navigation

Can anyone recommend a plug-in, or modified HTML code that permits display of a PDF that I host on my website, but still keep sections of the web-page available for 1) navigation; 2) copyright/contact notices at page bottom; and 3) side-column for additional navigation?
A WordPress plug-in would be nice, but not essential.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<embed src="path/to/file.pdf" width="500" height="700">`

Obviously you should change the attributes so it shows the file you want at the size you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `embed` tag. The process is explained in further detail [here](http://www.lancelhoff.com/embed-pdf-in-wordpress/).

Answer (score 2):

It can't really be done without a specific plug-in (like those offered by [scribd.com](http://support.scribd.com/forums/33626/entries/23405)), as browsers may be set up to open PDF in an external application. That would leave that portion of your page empty then.

See also [Best Way to Embed PDF in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/best-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use iframe, but i don't think this would be a good choice for WP.